# An special isometric embedding

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be  a Riemannian manifold and $\gamma$ be a non closed geodesic.
Is there an isometric embedding of $M$ into some $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ which send $\gamma$ into an straight line?
The second question: Assume $M$ is foliated with a family of non closed geodesics. Is there an isometric embedding of $M$ into $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ which send the family of geodesics to a familly of geodesics of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concerning the first question, what about an irrational geodesic in a torus? Since it has accumulation points, it cannot be mapped isometrically to a straight line.